# Makefile combine similar rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have in my makefile some similar rules:

```
include .env
include .env.local


var/make/.env: .env | var/make
    @sed 's/=/?=/' $< > $@

var/make/.env.local: .env.local | var/make
    @sed 's/=/?=/' $< > $@

var/make:
    mkdir $@
```

Is there a way to make a generic rule ?

```
var/make/.env*: name-matching-previous-.env* | var/make
    @sed 's/=/?=/' $< > $@
```

.env* being one file at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
var/make/.en%: .en% | var/make
    @sed 's/=/?=/' $< > $@
```

The `%` matches the variable part of the target name. (The target must end in `en%` and not `env%` because the `%` cannot match an empty string.)